# UFT - close test after X minutes

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am running several tests, one after another, on UFT.
I was wondering if there is an internal timer that could help me to skip test that got stuck and to proceed to the next test.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as a separate process using VBScript. (Not within QTP itself).

I have a `runner` file (runner.vbs) which invokes all the QTP/UFT scripts one by one. If  a test does not complete it in 10 mins, it stops the test/kills QTP, relaunches & proceed with the next step.

Use QTP's `Automation Object Model` for the same.

Comment: I am using the same method. Could you please post your code from runner file?

Comment: @MaxZemsky, unfortunately, I can not post the code now. But if you let me know the issue you are facing in implementing this, I could help you. Thanks.